# In MSSQL when do you use the @ symbol and when do you not?

Tags: sql-server, triggers, sql-server-2012

In MSSQL I know you declare and set variables like this for example

```sql
DECLARE @CONTNUMBER VARCHAR(10)
SET @CONTNUMBER= 'ABC1234567'
```

However, I've come across this issue when using a trigger and setting a variable in the select statement.

```sql
SELECT SMS.VEHICLE, @CONTNUMBER = SMS.CONTNO, SMS.ITEMNO, SMS.[STATUS], ...
```

[image]

But the error message disappears when I omit the leading **@** symbol

```sql
SELECT SMS.VEHICLE, CONTNUMBER = SMS.CONTNO, SMS.ITEMNO, SMS.[STATUS] ...
```

[image]

So my question is, when do I use and when do I omit the **@** symbol when using variables?

TYIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @TomTom mentions, you can't assign a variable and return a result set in the same `SELECT`.

In your code, `SELECT CONTNUMBER = SMS.CONTNO` is the same as `SELECT SMS.CONTNO AS CONTNUMBER` - you're just aliasing the output column.
This is covered here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176104.aspx

Also, variables are covered here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff848809.aspx

Comment: Ah of course! So I either need to set all the result columns to variables or remove the columns that aren't going to be used.

Answer (score 1):

You use the @ when you reference a variable.

The error is not the @ - it is mixing @ and not @ output.

If you bother reading the error message it tells you so. You can not have assignments (@variable =) and data retrieval (SMS.Vehicle into the output) within one statement.